# Read and write rich text files from TinyMCE in php

Tags: php, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am making a file uploader and editer in PHP using the TinyMCE rich text editor.

1. Which all files/types can be edited in TinyMCE.
2. Whats best was to edit a server file in TinyMCE.
3. How do i save to file edited in TinyMCe and what format should i save.

Sample code will be helpful.

In case tinymce is not right editor, please just another open source rich text editor.

Answer (score 3):

TinyMCE is just a **WYSIWYG** editor which means that it cannot read or write content to files, but it can interpret html to visual texts. 
You can exchange html between TinyMCE and you php code then write it as you want into files.
You can use some APIS to convert your files content into HTML to read it, these are some links to read write MS Word Content

- [How can I display Word documents in a textarea using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217969/how-can-i-display-word-documents-in-a-textarea-using-php)
- [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

Regards
NiL